# Get DataFrame of indexed value of value indexed of from a DF for the whole column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```py
>>> df
        a       b        c
foo  john  george  micheal
bar  sean   david      sam
```

Now I want a DataFrame which has only first two characters of all columns by processing the above.
So after some statement, `df` should become:

```py
>>> df
        a    b     c
foo     jo   ge    mi
bar     se   da    sa
```

I have tried options like : `df['a'].str[:2]`, this works but it only satisfies for one column, if I try for multiple columns like `df[df.columns].str[:2]` or `df[:].str[:2]` It throws error.
So how can I achieve that?

Comment: if your df isnt very big you can try `df.applymap(lambda x: x[:2])`

Comment: Use, `df = df.transform(lambda s: s.str[:2])`?

Comment: Yes, @ShubhamSharma and @anky, it works. @andy I have another ```df``` with 2895 columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `apply`

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:2]))

    1   2   3
0  jo  ge  mi
1  se  da  sa
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some quick vectorized solution. I have got one solution which seems faster than other solutions by creating a new DataFrame of values of Old DataFrame whose Indexing I have done using [numpy's dtype operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) and used column name of older DataFrame:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.values.astype('<U2'),columns=df.columns)
```

As I had DataFrame with huge number of columns, when I did `timeit` on a dummy `df` with same number of columns:

@ScootCork's Answer:

```py
>>> %t -n10 df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:2])
3.23 ms ± 735 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@anky's Comment:

```py
>>> %t -n10 df.applymap(lambda x: x[:2])
2.1 ms ± 404 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@Shubham Sharma's Comment:

```py
>>> %t -n10 df.transform(lambda s: s.str[:2])
2.56 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

My Solution:

```
>>> %t -n10 pd.DataFrame(df.values.astype('<U2'),columns=df.columns)
600 µs ± 95.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```